# How to transfer the apt keyring to another computer

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, gnupg

I'm currently moving my installation of Ubuntu from one laptop to another. Both laptops run Ubuntu 14.04. I moved my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, the contents of my home directory, and installed all packages from the old laptop on the new one. Now I want to transfer the apt keyring, because I think it will be easier than tracking down all the keys and installing them manually. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `apt-key` command can export all trusted keys:

```
apt-key exportall > trusted-keys
```

Copy the `trusted-keys` file to the other system and import them:

```
sudo apt-key add trusted-keys
```

Exporting via `apt-key` doesn't need root privilege, but importing does.

Comment: I am getting this error: "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found."